# How ubuntu works around licensing to deliver ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Tags: ffmpeg

I thought philosophy of linux was "open source, maintained, non-encumbered by patents, not full of security issues, meet generic open source best practices" How is package under ubuntu-restricted-extras provided by ubuntu?

There are some distro where we need to compile ffmpeg.

So how is ubuntu-restricted-extras provided?

> Many multimedia formats are patented. Even the most popular formats
>   like MP3 for audio and H.264 for video are subject to a huge number of
>   patents. Patent holders form organizations that pool their patents and
>   extract license fees for distributing such software. Linux
>   distributions don’t want to pay patent licensing fees every time they
>   let someone download their software for free.

**Is ubuntu paying for us to get these downloaded?**

[image]

Comment: This question seems vague as currently written. "How" is via apt, but I suspect you are really asking about licensing? It's not clear. Does https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Legal Notice Patent and copyright laws are different depending on the country you are in. You will need to get legal advice if you are unsure whether a particular patent or restriction applies to a media format you wish to use in your country.

I am not a lawyer so take these pointers as from a user but ...

- `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is a metapackage. The actual packages are NOT on the installer; Canonical does not need to pay a fee for a metapackage.
- It is up to the individual user to access if it is legal to use these. Mind the last sentence at the option: by checking this you accept the EULA. The EULA is not shown from the installer but accessible through the documentation.

> I thought philosophy of linux was "open source, maintained, non-encumbered by patents, not full of security issues, meet generic open source best practices"

That does not mean an individual user can not install proprietary software.